# How to convert single column in pandas dataframe to multiple new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I would like to take a given column and use its values as (multiple) new columns in a data frame. It looks like a pivot but without index.

If I have a data frame such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": [l for l in "AAABBB"], "val": np.random.random(6)})
```

Example data:

```
  name       val
0    A  0.600525
1    A  0.316421
2    A  0.744816
3    B  0.818978
4    B  0.647259
5    B  0.455111
```

I would like to group by the column "name" but I do not want to aggregate the results. I want to have a new column A and a new column B that contain the values in column "val".

```
name         A         B
0     0.600525  0.818978
1     0.316421  0.647259
2     0.744816  0.455111
```

The index doesn't matter here and of course, the number of values in A and B is not the same.

Comment: Check Q and A question 10

Comment: I am not sure this is the same question. I do not want to count the values of A or B. I want the values in column val. The question 10 is effectively the same, but the answer do a cumulative sum.

Comment: that is cumcount not cumsum .

Comment: Yes but I neither want to count nor to sum. I would like the values without any operation.

Comment: You just miss the index , cumcount is to create the index for each name

Comment: Ah ! Ok, I understand. Do you have the possibility to complete the answer of question 10 to give a complete solution ?

Comment: I will contact Pir to include that

Comment: If you say *the number of values in A and B is not the same*, then the example should reflect that, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({"name": [l for l in "AAABBBBB"], ...`. You're not doing *aggregate* and you're not doing *filter values on a given column* and that's not what 'groupby` does anyway: you mean to say *"pivot, using column `name` to make new frame's columns"*. Best not to reference so many keywords to explain what you're *not* doing - this question unwantedly matched searches for all sorts of unrelated queries, e.g. *[pandas] name result of aggregate*